# preguntar si deseo salir del programa con todas sus variaciones (si-Si-sI-SI-s-S)

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

El programa preguntará al usuario si desea finalizar o no, en caso que diga que "si" deberá terminar la ejecución.
No se como hacer para que funcione bien, para salir tengo que presionar variantes de (si-Si-sI-SI-s-S)

```
do{

    cout<<"\n Presione (si/s) para salir del programa: "; cin>>salir;

}while(salir=="si" || salir=="Si" || salir=="sI" || salir=="SI" || salir=="S" || salir=="S");
```

codigo completo:

```
int main(){

    int number;
    string salir="";
    string mes[]= {"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"};

    do{

        system("cls");

        cout<<" Ingrese un numero: "; cin>>number;

        if ( number < 1 || number > 12 ) {
            cout<<" Numero fuera del rango...";
        }
        cout<<endl<<" "<<mes[number-1]<<endl;

    cout<<"\n Presione (si/s) para salir del programa: "; cin>>salir;
    }while(salir=="si" || salir=="Si" || salir=="sI" || salir=="SI" || salir=="S" || salir=="S");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convierte la cadena en minúsculas usando `tolower` y así solo válidas dos casos `if(salir_minus == "si" || salir_minus == "s")`

Comment: El while mientras la condición se cumple sigue iterando. Es decir, si la opción es "SI" va a seguir dentro, que es lo contrario que tú quieres

Answer (score 2):

Para simplificar la causística, lo suyo es pasar la cadena a mayúsculas o a minúsculas, la decisión ya depende de cada uno. Al hacer esto simplificas las condiciones, ya que evitas casos duplicados:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

// ...

boost::algorithm::to_lower(salir);
if (salir == "s" || salir == "si" )
{
    // ...
}
```

Por otro lado, date cuenta que has programado el condicional justamente al revés. Tu intención, entiendo, es que el programa abandone el bucle cuando el usuario presione `s` o `si` (en cualquiera de sus variantes). Sin embargo, el condicional del bucle está programado para hacer justamente lo contrario.

Para que el bucle se abandone al introducir `si` deberías dejarlo así:

```
} while (salir != "s" &&  salir != "si" );
```

Comment: En la condicion del bucle me di cuenta que lo hice al reves, gracias me funciono el programa